# File system performance and the Unix API

Tags: unix, performance, file-system

A 1994 book called 'The Design and Implementation of a Log-structured file system' contains the claim "We have implemented a prototype log-structured file system called Sprite LFS; it outperforms current Unix file systems by an order of magnitude for small-file writes while matching or exceeding Unix performance for reads and large writes." That would seem on the face of it to constitute a compelling case to start using the file system in question, which raises the question of why this did not happen.

The Unix Haters Handbook claims this is because Sprite LFS not only was not compatible with the Unix API, but could not be; that user-visible aspects of the Unix API *preclude* high performance in any file system that retains compatibility. Granted that this book disclaims impartiality by its very title, I'm still interested in whether they are right.

Did the classic Unix API indeed preclude high-performance file systems like Sprite LFS? If so, what features of the API were responsible for this? (And how was the problem eventually resolved? I haven't seen anyone claim modern Linux file systems lack performance, and I'm under the impression Linux retains a high degree of backward compatibility.)

Comment: I don't know whatproblem the UHH was talking about, but it should be noted that ZFS (which I believe manages similar performance to Sprite) and was in use in Solaris (which, being a System-V derivative, is much closer to traditional Unix than Linux ever has been) starting from only a handful of years after the UHH was published, so whatever the issue was, it must have been easy to resolve.

Comment: Without a clear definition what _"Performance"_ means in this context, and in _which setup it is to be measured_, _what defines a filesystem in this context_ and _what parts are considered_, no clear answer to the question and regarding any of the mentioned claims can be given.

Comment: It should be noted that "current" filesystems in 1994 were mostly careful-write and didn't include logging or journalling: other than JFS1, I can't think of any mainstream filesystems at that time which included features like that. XFS and UFS didn't come out until 1994, possibly after the book was written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The Sprite LFS paper](https://web.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/papers/lfs.pdf) explains some of the performance issues its designers were trying to solve:

- lack of locality (even if FFS tries to keep individual files’ blocks contiguous on disk, they end up separated from the inode, and often separate from related files);
- synchronous writes.

The first issue is indeed driven by Unix-like semantics: Unix-like file systems always end up with concepts representing directories, files, and inodes. The second issue has seen common practice move back and forth over the years, and isn’t intricately tied to Unix-like semantics (although the definitions of `sync` operations do impose some constraints).

A variety of techniques have been used to address locality concerns, starting with [block groups](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/ext2intro.html#subsection:ext2fs:allocation) in `ext2`, more “intelligent” pre-allocation (and additional APIs allowing programs to tell the file systems about their allocation patterns), and moving to tree-structured file systems more recently.

Write performance has been addressed using a number of techniques too: for example, dropping fully-synchronous operations in favour of barriers, and using techniques from log-based file systems, re-implemented as the journal in journalling file systems.

As proof that logging file systems aren’t inherently incompatible with Unix-like semantics, you can look at real log-structured file systems which implement POSIX semantics, such as [NILFS2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NILFS). I’m not actually convinced that Sprite LFS itself is incompatible with Unix-like semantics; the paper doesn’t support this, and the UHH doesn’t give enough detail...

Comment: Actually the synchronous IO is very much a Posix thing. On other operating systems, (I'm thinking mainly of VMS and NT) you can issue an IO request and then go off and do other things while it completes.

Comment: @JeremyP you can do that in POSIX too, with `O_NONBLOCK`. The big POSIX requirement there on file systems is that any `read` after a `write` (even a non-blocking one) must return the written data.

Comment: No it's not the same. Non blocking reads and write still operate synchronously, they just return prematurely if the IO operation can't be done.

Comment: @JeremyP ah yes, you’re right, the real equivalent would be AIO. That said, the synchronicity issues with regards to performance, especially for writes, have been largely dealt with by caches etc. (which is one of the reasons why POSIX AIO never got anywhere).

Comment: And the synchronous model is simpler for the programmer. However, I don't see anything in the paper that precludes implementing the Posix IO model on top of an asynchronous API.

Comment: All modern OSes (NT, VMS, Unix etc.) support both async and synchronous IO.  But Unix is synchronous by default, and it permeates the libraries, standard utilities, etc.  VMS, by comparison, is largely async by default.  As I understand it, the guys behind Unix Haters felt that this was a major design error for scalability.

Comment: It's a lot easier to provide synchronous I/O calls on top of an I/O system that's fundamentally asynchronous, than it is to do the reverse.